# Angular $http.get always get ERROR consuming local Restful Service

Tags: java, javascript, json, angularjs, rest

I have an error and I am getting confuse, I have created a simple Java EE 7 project using Jersey.

I am returning this class in my Rest Rervice:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class LocationDTOx {

    private Long id;        
    private String tittle;    
    private String description;        
    private Long parent;

    //Getter and setters...
```

And in my service class i Have:

```
@Path("/location")
public class LocationService {

    @GET
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/findlocation")
    public LocationDTOx findLocation() {
        System.out.println("findlocation");
        try {
            LocationDTOx x = new LocationDTOx();
            x.setDescription("Description");
            x.setId(0l);
            x.setParent(null);
            x.setTittle("Tittle ...");
            return x;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LocationService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }    

}
```

I am 100% sure that my rest it is working , if I put this in my browser:

http://localhost:8080/BIReportL-war/rest/location/findlocation

I get this Json String:

{"description":"Description","id":0,"tittle":"Tittle ..."}

The deal is in my angular code, the code where I am calling the rest service from angular it is getting executed but it is just giving me the error part:

```
app.controller('questionsController', function ($scope, $http) {
    //var url = "http://localhost:8080/BIReportL-war/rest/location/findlocation";
    //var url = "http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php";
    var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/BIReportL-war/json.json";
    $http.get(url)
        .success(
            function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("success");   
            })
        .error(function(data, status, headers) {
          alert('Repos status ' + status + ' --- headers : ' + headers);
        })
        .finally(
            function() {
        });
});
```

I have with comments another local URL to a dummy json file that I can access it by that browser, and also I get the same result an error, the weird thing is that I tried with this rest public json file:

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php

And I get the success !! I don't know why, what I am doing or what I have wrong, I mean when I try with my local rest service, I see that it is getting called in the logs, that is a fact, but the angular client is getting into an error.

Thanks in advance for your help !

I am using:
*Glassfish V4
*Angular

Well, was about the CORS Issue I just put my rest as below, so here is the SOLUTION:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/findlocation")
    public Response findLocation() {
        System.out.println("findlocation");
        try {
            LocationDTOx x = new LocationDTOx();
            x.setDescription("Description");
            x.setId(0l);
            x.setParent(null);
            x.setTittle("Tittle ...");

            return Response.ok()
                    .entity(x)
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT")
                    .build();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LocationService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What does your error actually say?

Comment: Do you mix 127.0.0.1 and localhost ?

Comment: Yes , I have mixed, there is no problem just to try if I get something different, that was not the case ...

Comment: Well in my error code, I print the status and it comes with a value with 0 (Zero), I do not know if I can get a more detailed string about it.

Comment: it looks like you are facing CORS issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If AngularJS is accessing your local REST API, the fact that you're running it in a browser on a *different port*, it counts as a different origin, per the rules of CORS (separate port means separate origin).

> Two pages have the same origin if the protocol, port (if one is
>   specified), and host are the same for both pages.

For your Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header, either set it to all via *, or specify the alternate ports explicitly. This has to do with the fact that your browser (and AngularJS) are attempting to play by the rules, which you can find on [MDN's page on same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

These "rules" don't apply when you load the resource directly in your browser, as the origin (page your browser is loading from) is the same port, as you're loading *just* the resource, at that origin (plus port).

[Edit]

The CORS standards included adherence to certain response headers, such as Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Methods.

References:

- [MDN's page on access control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)
- [HTML5Rocks.com tutorial on CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)

[/Edit]

Comment: Than you I will try, it sound like that is what is happening to me, because my angular app is running in different port thant the rest api

Comment: I am kind of new in Angular (1 month) how can I do that?

Comment: It has to be a part of the response header; aka- from the Jersey REST server on 8080. This is server side and really doesn't have anything to do with Angular, as any front-end _adhering to CORS rules_ would experience the same thing. Since the JS implementation respects CORS, it considers the other port a different server and should, if you check you DevTools network request, see a "pre-flight" request of type OPTIONS. It's supposed to find the response headers of Access-Control-Allowed-Origin and Access-Control-Allowed-Methods, for instance.

Comment: Thank you, that was my problem :) thanks for your help. I had no idea why

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Once you run into it a couple times, it tends to sear itself into your memory ;-)

If you found the answer sufficient, please feel free to mark it as 'accepted'.

Answer (score 0):

Your Jersey service is using GET (@GET) while your Angular client is using POST ($http.post(url)).

Change the Angular code to $http.get and you're good to go.

Your example of http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php is working because it responds to both POST and GET, however for your scenario GET is clearly the correct HTTP verb.

Comment: Thank you, I have changed it, maybe I put post as result of a lot of test to make it works !, I have updated it to 'get' and it with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use relative url? `var url = "/BIReportL-war/json.json";`

Can you post here the entire error?

I agree with @pankajparkar it might be a CORS problem.

(Sorry for posting this 'answer', I don't have enough points for comments)

Comment: json.json is {"name":"dummy"} what is CORS?

Comment: [cross origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: how can I get entire error? I just print it with alert the status comes with a 0 value.