# Read Json data and display it according to drop down selcect list using angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

I am new to Angularjs. I want to read data from json file and display data according to the item selected in drop down list.
For example if I select particular "Region" in drop down list region, it will  show data of that region only. Any Hint to do this. my controller function.
Thanks in advance.

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/portalserver/static/launchpad/data.json") .success(function (response){
                  $scope.names = response.regions;
                  angular.forEach(data.regions,function(key,value){
                                  $scope.regions.push(value);
                 });
       });
```

I have done code to access from local system by giving file name in $http.get() method. but for the url above it's not working. Showing error "The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at localhost:8080/portalserver/static/launchpad/data.json. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling COR"

Comment: what is the structure of your json file ?

Comment: one way to do this is to set a filter and only show data of the specific region

Comment: Show the json object

Comment: Is there any issue you get when compile the code???

Comment: I have done code to access from local system by giving file name in $http.get() method. but for the url above it's not working. Showing error "The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/portalserver/static/launchpad/data.json. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling COR".

Comment: CORS rules mean that a different port means a different origin. Either serve both from the same port, proxy it, or see if you can add an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with a value of * to the network response that serves your json file (from localhost:8080). I went into the details further in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30824927/1720082).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I have created a plunker for you](http://plnkr.co/edit/2shyv7OmQQnqqSSPmpoB). Hope this clears your issues.

In my code i have created dropdowns and few span tags.
The span is rendered when I set ng-show value (true or false) in the controller when getChange(ID) function is called.

```
    <select ng-model="dropdownModel" ng-options="dropdown.ID as dropdown.Title for dropdown in dropdowns" ng-change="getChange(dropdownModel)"></select>
      <br><br>
        <span ng-show="showAL">Selected Alabama</span>\
        <span ng-show="showFL">Selected Florida</span>
        <span ng-show="showCA">Selected California</span> 
  <span ng-show="showDE">Selected Delaware</span>
```

My controller code

```
$scope.getChange = function(dID) {
    if (dID === 'AL') {
      $scope.showAL = true;
    } else {
      $scope.showAL = false;
    }

    if (dID === 'FL') {
      $scope.showFL = true;
    } else {
      $scope.showFL = false;
    }

    if (dID === 'CA') {
      $scope.showCA = true;
    } else {
      $scope.showCA = false;
    }

    if (dID === 'DE') {
      $scope.showDE = true;
    } else {
      $scope.showDE = false;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use angular **filter** on page or on controller if you want.

on page displaying regins on the basis of **selectedRegion**

```
<div ng-repeat="region in regions | filter:selectedRegion">
    <span>{{region.name}}</td>
</div>
```

You can check more details on filter here 
[Angular Js Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)